# Trimming a SQL Server 2016 database table using SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server 2016 database that looks like this:

```
ID     Value    Group     SYSDATE
-------------------------------------    
1       85       X      '2017-08-15'
2       87       Y      '2017-08-15'
3       934      Z      '2017-08-15'
4       85       X      '2017-08-14'
5       87       Y      '2017-08-14'
6       934      Z      '2017-08-14'
7       85       X      '2017-08-13'
8       87       Y      '2017-08-13'
9       934      Z      '2017-08-13'
7       85       X      '2017-08-12'
8       87       Y      '2017-08-12'
9       934      Z      '2017-08-12'
....
```

The table represents data from the same source that is usually the same but may change.  So I pull it every day.

I only want to keep the data with the top two SYSDATES at any time.

1. I'm not experienced in SQL and would appreciate some guidance on how to do the query.
2. Can someone advise how to set up a job in Job Agent to do this?

I think I can figure out how to get the top one SYSDATE info using MAX but not top two dates.

Any help/guidance/direction appreciated.

EDIT

Desired output:

```
ID     Value    Group     SYSDATE
------------------------------------ 
1       85       X      '2017-08-15'
2       87       Y      '2017-08-15'
3       934      Z      '2017-08-15'
4       85       X      '2017-08-14'
5       87       Y      '2017-08-14'
6       934      Z      '2017-08-14'
```

in the table (i.e., delete all data with a SYSDATE older than the second newest date)

Comment: Can you add your expected output in the question?

Comment: In your sample data, the expected output would be everything from 8/14 and 8/15?

Comment: Please see edit.  @Jason yes.

Comment: @Nayak please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? One of the ways:

```
SELECT ID, Value, GROUP, SYSDATE
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE SYSDATE IN (SELECT TOP 2 SYSDATE
                    FROM TABLE_A
                    ORDER BY SYSDATE DESC);
```

Comment: So you need to do a sub query in the where statement?  That always throws me. I haven't gotten comfortable when and where that has to be done.

Comment: You will get more comfortable when you start using it more often :-)

Answer (score 1):

The sub query get dates not to be deleted.
The where clause checks date which are not be deleted.

```
DELETE TABLE_A
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE CAST(SysDate AS DATE) NOT IN
(
    SELECT TOP 2 dates
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST(SysDate AS DATE) AS dates
        FROM TABLE_A
    ) AS Dates
    ORDER BY dates desc
)
```